# Regular Expression to integrate with c++ using regex_match

Tags: c++, regex

I am new to C++ and currently working on a simple application to use some validation of strings using regular expressions.

I was trying to use Regular Expression - `\bdevid\b` - This regular expression validates to true if the string contains exact word `devid`.

I intended c++ code to do the same validation. To  use this in c++ I included

```
#include <regex>
```

and coded as below-

```
bool IsValid() 
{
 if (std::regex_match ("devid", std::regex("\bdevid\b") ))
  {
      return 1 ;
  }
  else 
  {
      return 0;
  }
}
```

But this goes into false section in above code. Can anyone tell if there is anything i am missing or my approach is not correct. 
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to double up the escape characters: `"\\bdevid\\b"`. The first backslash is swallowed when the string is compiled, so you need another one to get through to the regex engine.

Comment: @m.buettner it throws a std::regex_error when I tried that.

Comment: You may need to use the extended or ECMAScript compatibility modes.

Comment: Thanks m.buetter!! It worked by putting extra backslash!

Comment: Also, maybe you want [`regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) which will succeed if the regex is found anywhere inside the sequence -- [`regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) will only succeed if the regex matches the entire input sequence.

Comment: note: you can simply `return std::regex_match(...`